# How to check git submodule status from the root repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo, let's call it `test`. Inside that repo, I want to create a submodule that points to another existing repo called `tools`. I want to be able to modify files in both repos, then open a git bash from `test`, do a `git status`, and see that I have modified or untracked files in both repos. I am expecting to modify and push to both repos in the course of this project, and I want to avoid having to do a `git status` in two different places. How can I do that?

I have tried `git status --ignore-submodules=none` and that did not show submodule information even when I had modified files in the submodule.

If using submodules for this is not the best way to do this, I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `git status --ignore-submodules=none` and that did not show submodule information even when I had modified files in the submodule

It should have: check the status of the submodule themselves with `git submodule status` and see if they are actually well initialized.

Comment: You're right - I wiped out my test repo and did the steps to create a submodule all over again, and this time, it worked. Also, `git status` in the root repo seems to also check submodule status, even without the `--ignore-submodules=none` command. Thanks!